# How can I solve the error `Not found. Authentication passthru.` for Omniauth GitHub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I implemented OmniAuth with OmniAuth-Github, and it worked–until it didn’t.

I’m currently getting the following error: `Not found. Authentication passthru.`

Accompanied with:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/github" for ::1 at 2020-01-02 14:25:49 +0800
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#passthru as HTML
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2)
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 548)
```

**Here's my code, which is also viewable here: https://github.com/mirhamasala/lw_city_guide**

```
# routes.rb

devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

```
# the routes

user_github_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/github(.:format)
users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru

user_github_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/github/callback(.:format)
users/omniauth_callbacks#github
```

```
# devise.rb

config.omniauth :github, ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET']
```

```
# controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def github
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication # This will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Github") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.github_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

```
# user.rb

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:rememberable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[github]

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
    user.username = auth.info.nickname
    user.avatar = auth.info.image
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.github_profile = auth.info.urls.GitHub
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, after upgrading to Rails 6, I didn’t have `jquery_ujs` anymore, which is needed for the `link_to` helpers to work.

Comment: We're experiencing the same thing after we upgraded to Rails 6 recently.  What was your fix to this @Mirtha Masala?

Comment: This is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59560170/8018811 @VinnyQ77

Comment: the link stackoverflow.com/a/59560170/8018811 is just redirecting to this same answer? is the link broken?

Comment: The link isn't broken. It's this answer that worked for me.